# swift / StackView alignment of image next to a label with size control

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I want to make the profile image beside the username using UIStackview but when I do it the image expand to the whole stack view.

What I did I Stacked the 3 labels one by one then together

So the question? 
how to control image size and make it stick there without expanding.

I want it to be like the image below

[image: this is my project]

[image: I want it to be like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin your image view height and width.

**Edit :** Stack work on single axis. Either vertical or horizontal. But not both. If you want to put your Image view in stack you can use nested stack views. Use a horizontal stack view with an Image view and a vertical stack view.

Find sample storyboard [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4cHSbEcSak3MUNxZE5NMG5zZlU/view?usp=sharing)!

[[image]][[image]][3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4cHSbEcSak3MUNxZE5NMG5zZlU/view?usp=sharing)[image]

Comment: I did stack the image two but you wrap it inside a UIView, Can't the image stacked so this will make sure it stacked perfectly inside the tableviewcell

Comment: Stacks are either vertical or horizontal, not both. You can check more on them https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/ Don't forget to mark this answer if it worked for you! Cheers!